# Number of columns in LIBSVM dataset

Tags: libsvm

Is there a quick way to count the number of columns in a LIBSVM data set? So the obvious way is to look through every single entry and take maximums, but I was hoping there was a better way that I didn't think of. Counting the number of rows is easy, since it's the same as the number of rows in the text file. I'm using C++.

Comment: This is off topic for CV.

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to review our [tour](http://stats.stackexchange/tour).  You may want to ask your question on http://stackoverflow.com.